# Choice of database to insert data from Scala code

Tags: database, scala, persistence, akka-persistence

I have a project written in Scala where I want to save incoming data to some database. My mentor suggested Persistence (Akka), but from what I've read it seems like that just keeps track of the state so that a former state can be recovered if it crashes.

Sorry for my inexperience in this field, I just want to get some input regarding whether it is possible to use Persistence in this case. Otherwise, suggestions of alternative approaches would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Persistence in this case would certainly be possible. As you noticed, it's a specific add-on for the akka actors, so it's only adapted in this case.

That being said, "save incoming data to some database" is a bit too broad of a mission to really say if it's the most fitted solution for you !

I encourage you to dig the subject with your mentor, since you're lucky to have one ! :-D

And finally, if it turns out there was a misunderstanding of what you needed, I'd suggest looking at slick, which is afaik a very classic choice for "writing data to some database" !